# rxJava monitor task until complete

Tags: android, rx-java, dagger-2

Here is a use case I am trying to resolve with rxJava and Dagger2 in my android app.

1. Load recording details
2. Check backend server if HLS transcode exists (REST Call)

   - If exists, monitor until process is 100% (REST Call every n seconds until 100%)
   - If does not exist, don't call monitor process

The REST Calls are injected through a dagger component. I am struggling with setting up rxJava to create a monitor that will refresh the REST Call until the process is 100% and stops, or the user just backs out the screen.

I am not sure I am asking this question in the correct way, so if an update is required, please let me know.

Here is a link to my presenter on [github repo](https://github.com/MythTV-Clients/MythtvPlayerForAndroid/blob/clean_architecture/presentation/src/main/java/org/mythtv/android/presentation/presenter/ProgramDetailsPresenter.java). This loads the data and needs to trigger the updates back to the fragment that is responsible for displaying data.

UPDATE: 2015-10-26 PM
I know this is probably a hack, but this is how I implemented the repeating delayed calls:

```
@Override
protected Observable buildUseCaseObservable() {

    Action1<List<LiveStreamInfo>> onNextAction = new Action1<List<LiveStreamInfo>>() {

        @Override
        public void call( List<LiveStreamInfo> liveStreamInfos ) {

            try {
                Thread.sleep( 5000 );
            } catch( InterruptedException e ) { }

        }

    };

    return this.contentRepository.liveStreamInfos( this.filename )
            .repeat( Schedulers.io() )
            .doOnNext( onNextAction );
}
```

Then, in the call method that establishes a subsriber:

```
private void getProgramDetails() {

    this.getProgramDetailsUseCase.execute(new ProgramDetailsSubscriber());

}
```

And the subscriber:

```
private final class LiveStreamInfosListSubscriber extends DefaultSubscriber<List<LiveStreamInfo>> {

    @Override
    public void onCompleted() {
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onError( Throwable e ) {
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onNext( List<LiveStreamInfo> liveStreamInfos ) {

        if( null != liveStreamInfos && !liveStreamInfos.isEmpty() ) {

            ProgramDetailsPresenter.this.showLiveStreamDetailsInView( liveStreamInfos.get( 0 ) );

            if( liveStreamInfos.get( 0 ).getPercentComplete() == 100 ) {

                ProgramDetailsPresenter.this.getLiveStreamsListUseCase.unsubscribe();

            }

        }

    }

}
```

The subscriber will unsubscribe from the observable once the percent complete reaches 100%, cancelling all future call. The benefit here is that this subscriber fires when a user initiates the transcode, creating the live stream, from within the app, or it picks it up from the backend is it is initiated from the backend web interface.

Answer (score 0):

How about adding .retry() with how often you want to retry and a large value for the number of retries to your rx observer. Then just unsubscribe from your source observable when exiting your fragment to stop the polling.

Comment: If I add a retry to the initial get, that will then emit that object back which will force a redraw of the elements on the screen. What about combining with a filter to restrict that?

Comment: Ah I see. Yeah a filter looks like it would work. As an aside, do you have the ability to modify the server side code? If so, have you considered changing the design of the REST endpoint that you're polling every n seconds to use comet/reverse polling? Doing this will make your server more scalable, and improve performance on your android client.

Comment: the backend is [mythtv](http://mythtv.org). I am not a backend developer, or I would try that out.  It would be great to not have to poll at all and just let the backend handle that. That being said, mythtv is open source, so, I could look into it. Its just time is all.